# Strange behavior of threads

Tags: multithreading, invoke, invokerequired

I’m writing an application that communicates with some hardware using the MODBUS protocol.
I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20929/Simple-Modbus-Protocol-in-C-NET-2-0) sample from Code Project.

While trying to optimize the code (mainly the `PollFunction` function), I've encountered with a very strange threads lock.

Instead of sending each line of string to the `DoGUIUpdate` delagate, I'm constructing a string array and sending it as a whole.

Doing so causes the application to crush with a `System.Reflection.targetParametercountException: Parameter count mismatch` error.

The original code:

```
public delegate void GUIUpdate(string paramString);
public void DoGUIUpdate(string paramString)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        BeginInvoke(new GUIUpdate(DoGUIUpdate), paramString);
    else
        lstRegisterValues.Items.Add(paramString);
}

private void PollFunction()
{
    ...
    string itemString;
    for (int i = 0; i < pollLength; i++)
    {
        itemString = "[" + Convert.ToString(pollStart + i + 40001) + "] , MB[" + Convert.ToString(pollStart + i) + "] = " + values[i];
        DoGUIUpdate(itemString);
    }
}
```

My code:

```
public delegate void GUIUpdate2(string[] paramString);
public void DoGUIUpdate2(string[] paramString)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        BeginInvoke(new GUIUpdate2(DoGUIUpdate2), paramString);
    else
    {
        lstRegisterValues.Items.Clear();
        lstRegisterValues.Items.AddRange(paramString);
    }
}

string[] valuesStrings;
private void PollFunction()
{
    ...
    valuesStrings = new string[pollLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < pollLength; i++)
    {
        valuesStrings[i] = "[" + Convert.ToString(pollStart + i + 40001) + "] , MB[" + Convert.ToString(pollStart + i) + "] = " + values[i];
    }
    DoGUIUpdate2(valuesStrings);
}
```

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think `BeginInvoke(new GUIUpdate2(DoGUIUpdate2), paramString);` is the problem...

the second parameter of "begininvoke" accepts a `param object[] params` which will result in the call `DoGuiUpdate(string1,string2,string3)` which is not what you want...

try encapsulate in the following way:

```
BeginInvoke(new GUIUpdate2(DoGUIUpdate2), new[]{ paramString });
```